# Detect if file was selected using CodeIgniter Input Class

Tags: codeigniter, input

I'm trying to detect if a file was selected using the CodeIgniter input class:

Using the Form Helper to output an upload input in my view:

```
echo form_upload('image', isset($ad)?$ad['image']:"", 'placeholder="Image" title="Please Choose A File"');
```

And in my controller:

```
private function handleUpdate()
{
  $image = $this->input->post('image');

  if($image != none && $image != "")
  {
    $this->handleImageUpload();
  }
}
```

This of course is a stripped down function, but to illustrate the problem: $image is always coming out empty.  What's going on?  Using CI 1.7.3

Comment: Ah, sorry about the $ad.  I meant to strip that away for the question.  It's an array being passed from the controller.  Contains the values from the database.  In retrospect, it shouldn't even be in my code, adds zero functionality as I don't think you can pre-populate upload inputs.  Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
  do_something();
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Should have realized that.  For some reason I though CodeIgniter stripped all the $_POST AND $_FILES variables... but no... just the $_POST.  Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: I tried this, but it is always TRUE. So I use $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] != ''

Comment: Use !empty() instead of isset().

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$_FILES` with uploading files.

`$this->input->post('image') == $_POST['image'];`

And make sure you use `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Wicked, thank you for pointing out $_FILES.  Not sure what that line of code you posted was about.  Did you mean to say $this->input->post('image') = $_FILES['image'] ?

Comment: I meant that $_FILES isn't $_POST

Answer (score 0):

**Thorpe Obazee** was right. This worked for me:

```
if ($this->input->post('img') == $_FILES['img'])
{
    //do upload and resize
}
```